# Add fragment identifiers to MCVE page sections for easy linking

Tags: feature-request, help-center, minimal-reproducible-example

Sometimes, when I link to the [MCVE page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I want to highlight one specific aspect using a [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). For instance, a question be minimal and complete, but not verifiable. It would be nice to be able to link to a specific section like this

- https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve#minimal
- https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve#complete
- https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve#verifiable.

Bonus points for subtly [highlighting the targeted heading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) so that it can be found if the user scrolls up or down, or if the screen is large enough to show multiple aspects.

Comment: Same for the individual [off-topic bullet-points](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: The same for *every* on-site 'help'-based page and resource; linking to a subsection of a given page should, really, be possible. Especially when the intent is to direct a user to a specific portion of that page.

Comment: The other way I wanted to link to http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty#awarded. As David says, every subsection should be linkable. And also for configuration pages, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current#private

Comment: The same for ... (•_•) ( •_•)>⌐■-■ (⌐■_■) ... every header, section, or list item on the site.

Comment: I too tried to do that on a number of occasions. This really should - and I fully expected it - to be possible.

Comment: @Oriol I meant "the other day".

Comment: Personally, I'm a huge fan of the way the [official python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) do this.  Every header/title/function signature is hyperlinkable, and overing over the text brings up a little hyperlink to that piece of text, which makes it very easy to identify the fragment name.