# Should my canonical about read_clipboard usage in Pandas be on Meta or Main?

Tags: discussion, questions, canonical

If you've ever tried answering questions in [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas), you'll know 90% of them cannot be answered unless the OP posts their data (or, at least a sample) that gives us an idea what they're working with and what their expected output is. Some seasoned askers understand this well and include code we can paste into our terminal that generates the data sample. Most askers, though, just paste a few rows of data from their terminal output, CSV, or spreadsheet and expect us to work off it.

Thankfully, pandas really knows how to make effective tools for devs, so they created [`pd.read_clipboard`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_clipboard.html) that can load DataFrames from your clipboard.

Often times I am asked by newbies, "how were you able to load the data in the question?" I usually direct them to the documentation or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31610889/4909087), but neither of those links cover important scenarios that need to be considered, such as

- preserving the index
- parsing data with whitespace in the columns
- reading series instead of DataFrames
- parsing columns of python objects

and so on. These cases need to be solved by a special application of various arguments that `pd.read_clipboard` offers in conjunction with other libraries, and some of them aren't always cut and dry.

This brings me to the crux of my question: **If one were to write a "beginner's manual" for `read_clipboard`, where should it go?**

I can think of the following options:

1. Make it a self-answered post on meta
2. Make it a self-answered post on SO main
3. Add an answer to [How to copy/paste DataFrame from Stack Overflow into Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610889/how-to-copy-paste-dataframe-from-stack-overflow-into-python)

Option 1 makes the most sense to me since such a post could be classified as tag-specific guidance on answering questions on Stack Overflow, within a particular tag. I'm not sure if we have other examples of this on meta. The other two examples I'm aware of for "tag specific guidance" are [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), both of which are closed, so that doesn't make Option 2 a promising one. Finally, Option 3 would make the post less discoverable, although I'm not sure it would be anyless discoverable than Option 1, which only a very small portion (active meta crowd, or anyone who goes searching for it) would actually see.

Look forward to hearing your thoughts. If you are interested to know more about the content of the post, I've created a rough draft with the topic outlines [here](https://gist.github.com/Coldsp33d/840f2e6730af66e29286c26315b6dfce).

Comment: @cigien that's very much a similar type of question to what I'm looking to post. You'll notice, however, that that post is locked. I have also seen meta discussions that discourage such QnA formats on main, so I'm not sure.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that you'd linked to it in the question itself, after I made the comment. My bad. fwiw, a community wiki on main does seem the best to me.

Comment: What is needed is, how to cut & paste to SO posts. A post should contain code including initialization that can be cut & pasted & run. If you want people to find them, use a title that is, creating a [mre] in that language.

Comment: "Finally, Option 3 would make the post less discoverable". IMHO, it's the opposite. Scattering information on several posts makes it less discoverable. I'm going to vote to close this new question as a duplicate of the older one, and later, if it gets closed, I'd ask for a merge. I think this is the best course of action since your question is basically an extension of the older one.

Comment: @Georgy please post an answer with your proposed actions (preferably before trying to shut the post down please), I'd like to see how the community votes on that option.

Comment: See also [Could we add a tag-specific MCVE page?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366424/155423)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It should be a self-answered canonical Q&A on the main site. But, when doing so, you need to follow the rules: you need to ask an actual question. It can't just be:

> "Beginner's Guide to `pd.read_clipboard`"

It needs to be something like:

> "How do I use `pd.read_clipboard` to do…<whatever it is you do with this thing—read a clipboard?>".

phrased as an actual question that can be answered. It's OK if the question is a bit broader than you might normally feel comfortable asking—it's meant to be a canonical. And it's always OK if answers are more comprehensive than what the question strictly asks for.

You can then link to this Q&A from answers or comments when appropriate. However, please *do not* use it as a way to close questions, unless the question is actually asking how to use `pd.read_clipboard`. Do not use it as a way to perform "RTFM" closures. Similarly, don't close questions that lack a minimal example as a duplicate of this. Such questions are not duplicates. They are lacking a minimal, reproducible example, and we have a close reason for that. Use it. Include a link to the Q&A explaining how to build such an example in a comment.

This question doesn't belong on Meta. It's a practical programming problem that, in your own experience, represents a skill that many Pandas users need but lack. That's a perfect case for a question on Stack Overflow. Meta is for questions *about* Stack Overflow. It's not discoverable on Meta, anyway. Which is also why you shouldn't try to cram it into a tag wiki (although you should definitely add a *link* to the completed Q&A to all of the applicable tag wikis).

Neither of the two questions you linked ([How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) or [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)) are closed. They're just locked from new answers, forcing all updates to a single, community-wiki answer. If appropriate, that same treatment can be applied to your new question, but I wouldn't be overly eager to do so.

As for the proposed option to add an answer to [How to copy/paste DataFrame from Stack Overflow into Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610889/how-to-copy-paste-dataframe-from-stack-overflow-into-python), I can't tell you if that's appropriate. That's a judgment call that needs to be made by someone who understands Pandas as something more than cute, black-and-white, bamboo-eating bears. What I can tell you is that, generally, multiple long-form answers to the same question don't work as well as just a single one. If this is a task that can be hived off into a separate question, I think it makes sense to do so. Add hyperlinks to cross-link the two questions at the relevant sections of the answers, if appropriate. But if it's really just an expansion of the existing question about copy/pasting DataFrames, then I don't think it merits a new question.

Comment: They're wiki locked, @cs95. (From the lock description shown to moderators: "Lock this post to encourage users to edit existing answers. Remember to remove unnecessary answers and to mark questions and their answers as Community Wiki posts.") I think that's reasonable. Don't you? I'm open to changing that status for those specific questions, if there's a compelling reason to do so, but I don't see one. As for the proposed new question, it might make sense to wiki lock it, but there's no rush on doing so.

Comment: Oh, sorry, for some reason I missed that initially in your answer. I assumed the lock was to prevent any more cv-pls wars on the question; evidently a lot of folks felt it was off topic for main.

Comment: "However, please do not use it as a way to close questions, unless the question is actually asking how to use pd.read_clipboard" this, freaking this. Many "how to debug" are the dumpster fire of "how to fix". Yes, debugging is part of the fixing process but doesn't solve it!

Comment: When asking a self-answered question, imagine you've got the wrong answer or the wrong piece of advice. If someone else was going to answer correctly, what question would they be answering? If you don't know, then you are writing a blog post, not a Q&A post.

Comment: That's very good advice, @JDB. I wholeheartedly agree. However, I firmly believe that even most "blog post"-style "questions" can be reformatted to be legitimate Q&A-style questions. It just requires having the correct intentions.