# What should I do when a Selenium question includes URL to third-party website?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, spam

When I read questions with [tag "Selenium"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium) I often see links to websites.

**Examples** of such questions that have not been closed:
[Unable to get images from skechers in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66611041/unable-to-get-images-from-skechers-in-python)
[How get value from field using Selenium java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66611752/how-get-value-from-field-using-selenium-java)
[When I login I see an attribute error in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66597642/when-i-login-i-see-an-attribute-error-in-selenium)
[Why xpath doesn't work properly for certain tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66512364/why-xpath-doesnt-work-properly-for-certain-tags)
[I want to get the IDs of categories (taxonomies) of custom post type in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66348671/i-want-to-get-the-ids-of-categories-taxonomies-of-custom-post-type-in-url)

My understanding is that according to rules this is not allowed. Instead, a minimal reproducible example should be added.
I am confused about what I should do, as sometimes having a link to a website really helps to see the issue. But at the same time spam is masked as an unexperienced user seeking help.

In the past, I have flagged some of these posts as spam, but sometimes my flag was declined.
I understand that flagging as spam has harsh consequences.
So is it better if I downvote the question and post a comment that the URL should be removed?
I can also flag the question as "in need of moderator intervention". Is this what I should do?

It is really not easy to distinguish whether the URL to a website is spam or included without spam intention.
So what is the correct action?

Edit: [This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405791/what-should-a-minimal-reproducible-example-include-for-problems-with-automati) about minimal reproducible example does not answer my question. I do not see how the minimal reproducible example rule should be enforced and what to do with smart spammers.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405791/what-should-a-minimal-reproducible-example-include-for-problems-with-automati). If this can be enforced then it would be great and would remove the dependence the question has on the website link being there. In the meantime, these are definitely not spam and shouldn't be flagged (giving them the benefit of the doubt so to speak...). But I would still recommend staying cautious. I have seen some "smart" spammers using the selenium tag on blatantly obvious spam.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Indeed I feel the number of smart spammers is increasing. And it is hard to tell sometimes. For me the examples I have provided are spam. But if you feel they are not, I am completely confused. How to enforce the minimal reproducible example rule?

Comment: Thank you @VLAZ I have updated my question with the reason why it does not answer my question.

Comment: @K.B. then I suggest you start working on mind reading software, because I don't think any of us can guess what the intention of putting a link in the question is. Is it supposed to be "go here, so I can get visits" or "go here because I cannot formulate my problem well". However, in both cases, it seems like the question should be closed until it becomes a proper question - answerable *without* an external link. Presumably a spammer won't do that and eventually the question would be roomba'd

Comment: @VLAZ I agree with you that the question should be closed until it becomes a proper question, but how should I flag the question? Low quality, missing debugging details? Or some other flag?

Comment: "*Needs debugging details - The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.*". You can then link the above Q&A in the comment. At least that's what I'd do if I were active on the Selenium tag.

Comment: I think this speaks more to a misunderstanding of what spam is than a misunderstanding of what to do with questions that contain links to production sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tough one. There was a recent post on [MCVE for Selenium](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405791/what-should-a-minimal-reproducible-example-include-for-problems-with-automati#comment829803_405791) - much of which holds true for web-scraping/automation in general. It can be a tall order for a new user to mock-up an example with all the required detail - also, if they knew all the required detail they might possibly solve their problem. For these questions, I prefer, where possible to leave in the URLs, and that the OP provides also the HTML they believe relevant.

Be cautious in terms of flagging spam and accept some cases might get through the net. In many cases, where you may suspect spam, I think it likely questions can better be handled as duplicates or flaggable/closable in other ways. There is also the scenario where the question is actually useful and not a duplicate.

In short, **I don't think targeting the removal of the URL is the solution**. Urls can be helpful, sometimes necessary. I think it is viewing the URL in the context of the question, and the OP's possible prior questions, and deciding if there is a more obvious reason to close/flag. If there is a history of low quality questions pertaining to certain domain(s) you are likely on firmer spam ground.

Regarding spam the following are useful:

1. [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260638/what-is-the-exact-definition-of-spam-for-stack-overflow#:~:text=A%20post%20should%20be%20marked,t%20care%20about%20your%20problem%22](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260638/what-is-the-exact-definition-of-spam-for-stack-overflow#:%7E:text=A%20post%20should%20be%20marked,t%20care%20about%20your%20problem%22).
2. [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor)