# How to have a "minimal reproducible example" with Vulkan

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, minimal-reproducible-example

I feel it's impossible to give a minimal reproducible example for [Vulkan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulkan) without dumping an entire GitHub repository into Stack Overflow, with a monstrosity of a question.

In normal circumstances, when the code is too much, one could find the problematic part using a debugger and then show that problematic part. But with Vulkan, the error could be caused due to a random typo of "1" to "0" a thousand lines above.

Validation layers can handle petty stuff like [segmentation faults](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault), but for rendering issues you have to at the very least show the entire pipeline, all the command buffers, the shaders, and other stuff.

Even the most minimal of minimal things will require about 200 lines + shaders and additional parts which seem to be relevant. Currently on Stack Overflow, people dump out 50 lines around the function causing the problem. This system kind of works after a few assumptions and time. Some never get answers, but most do, but this doesn't seem right for such an ordered and objective site like Stack Overflow.

How am I meant to ask a Vulkan question about the cause of a bug and provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Well you should be the one debugging, but the minimal reproducible example is more of a guideline instead of a hard rule, despite what other people may think. If you can't provide it, you can't provide it. If you can't provide it, your chance of getting an answer drastically diminishes though, as are your chances that the question will be well-received.

Comment: Side note: when I was doing low level game development programming directly against the API, I was frequently stuck on problems for a week. One time even over a month. It comes with the territory, programming against graphical APIs is damned hard. It helps to look for a community dedicated to game programming, Stack Overflow really isn't that.

Comment: @Gimby Yes I agree SO isn't really a site for low level graphics development. I need like some site where nobody complains for doing stupid things like loading the vertex shader twice instead of the fragment shader. We might need a graphicscodedebugging.stackexchange.com or maybe a different site altogether. Do you know of any such sites which don't look like 1990s dinosaur UI threads?

Comment: I would think that people in that specific tag would know what a MRE looks like for that tag - and   make allowances.  Maybe?

Comment: @ShambhavGautam If there's a particular library that you are using, it might be a good idea to see if they have a support forum, I had good luck with my OpenGL work with that. I was able to link my Github repo instead of having to paste a massive amount of code. Though... personally, I think graphics code questions are perfectly fine for SO, anyone following OpenGL, Vulkan, etc. should know they have entered the Twilight Zone of vexing, verbose, and mysterious APIs.

Comment: Also it's not just graphics programming, every real-time system I worked on had long / difficult code. If you've got a time consuming thing to do (like rendering) on a deadline you have to do it in batch, even if it ruins your encapsulation. You might like to redraw something in response to player input, but you can't, wait your turn until the end of the frame.

Comment: I have nothing against 200 lines of code minimal examples, personally. Minimal and small is not the same.

Comment: Related: [What should a 'minimal, reproducible example' include for problems with automating web browsers using Selenium?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405791/what-should-a-minimal-reproducible-example-include-for-problems-with-automati) The general ideas there should also apply here.

Comment: Anyone else find it ironic that an API named "Vulkan" was foisted upon the world by some of the most illogical people in the world of API design?

Comment: @MasonWheeler: No. Because: 1) "Vulkan" is the German word for "volcano", which is an allusion to the fact that Vulkan started as the Mantle API. Mantle being the stuff before it erupts from a volcano. The etymology of its name has nothing to do with Star Trek. 2) Vulkan may be verbose, but the design of its API is quite logical considering the design requirements of being a low-level, explicit, and extensible API that works in C and languages that speak C. Its complexity and verbosity are merely the result of the complexity and verbosity of its problem domain.

Comment: @MasonWheeler Vulkan may be verbose but it's extremely  intuitive due to its explicitness.Have you ever tried using Vulkan? Not a single bit of information that you pass to Vulkan is useless.It just asks you whatever you're going to do. And you're going to do a lot, that's why you have to answer a lot.In Scala, you say what you want to want, not how you achieve it, in OpenGL, you don't say what you want or how you achieve, you directly do it and in Vulkan, you say how you will achieve it, and the API figures out what you want and then you achieve it.Bad poetry.Doing so,is bug free and optimal.

Comment: Maybe a high level layer is needed on top of Vulkan (a Caldera perhaps) for those programmers who actually don't need all the low-level stuff and are happy to sacrifice a bit of performance in order to have a smaller, easier to use and less error prone API. Is Vulkan, due to its complexity maybe only for experts?

Comment: Do you have an example of such questions?

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis Basically all questions in the `vulkan` tag, with a few exceptions.

Comment: Well, I checked out some of the top rated and they are no longer than an average question. That's why I ask for links, though. Check out my last few questions to get an ifra what might be considered long.

Answer (score 29):

You're not going to get lots of help from people on meta who don't understand the problem.  To everyone else looking at this who isn't familiar with Vulkan, if you aren't working in graphics programming, let alone Vulkan, you literally can't comprehend how real and how big of a problem this is. MVCE's are not trivial in Vulkan, unlike OpenGL, the work required for code is dumped upfront, so you can't make a dinky 100 line program, you'd need at least a 1000 + lines.

The people in the Vulkan tags are smart. There's a lot of opportunity to ask a question without posting your entire code base, and it still be reproducible.

First, let’s reduce the context to what is absolutely necessary:

- Use validation layers, always.  There are other types of validation layers that are not enabled by default. The big one is `VK_VALIDATION_FEATURE_ENABLE_SYNCHRONIZATION_VALIDATION_EXT`.  This is a relatively new thing, and you'll have to enable this explicitly.
- Use VkConfig with your Vulkan SDK to enable these layers if you don't want to do this programmatically.
- Use RenderDoc to diagnose visualization issues before using SO.  You can also use this to provide context to your question. Half the time RenderDoc provides enough information to solve things like vertex transform issues.
- Remove synchronization issues as a possible avenue of bugs if you're sure that isn't it, and start looking at the same program. If removing synchronization fixes the issue, you've greatly reduced the possible locations where you could be having issues.

This will potentially cut down how often you need to go to SO to get a question answered, and help narrow down the issue.

Next we can separate Vulkan usages into several cases:

- Synchronization issues
- Shader issues
- Command issues.
- API issues.

You should be able to verify whether or not you're dealing with a synchronization related problem.  Because of the way synchronization works in Vulkan, you should be able to only supply what is going on in your core rendering loop and or async compute loops, and not the setup code.  This should be much less than the rest of the code base.

Shader issues can often allow one to only show only the shader(s) involved, which may be significantly less code than the entire code base. Even if the issue wasn't in the shader, what can happen is someone can verify that nothing is wrong with the shader, and that the issue *must* be somewhere else. To do this, you must have reasonable suspicion that the shader is actually the problem, and ideas why, otherwise, it's not very helpful to other readers.

Command submission issues might only require commands from a specific part of code.  Using the normal MVCE but for your own sake, you should be able to isolate commands which are actually relevant to your problem, then, if the code base is too big, only show the command recording.

API issues are things like using the wrong flag, not understanding nomenclature, etc... Obviously if it isn't a code issue, you don't need code, but usually when you have API issues, it's with a specific object, and the only reason you know about this object is the validation layers.  If you're sure you've exhausted your validation layer issues, you should be able to isolate only the code where this object exists, which should provide enough context for others to help.  With those kind of API misuse issues, we often don't even have to run the code ourselves to know what is wrong with it.

Comment: Have you used this "we can separate Vulkan usages into several cases:" yourself? If you have some graphics development experience, you'll know that the problem is NEVER where you expect it to be, otherwise, you'd have debugged it already and there would be no question to ask. Just like how rich people don't spend much because they became rich by not spending much in the first place. If the problem was where you expected, you would solved it after a bit of debugging and would never need to ask a question. Theoretically, you are right but practically, it won't work.

Comment: @ShambhavGautam: "*Theoretically, you are right but practically, it won't work.*" Well, if it isn't practical, if the only solution is to fling a gigantic mound of code at strangers on the internet and say "my problem is somewhere in there. Go find it," then SO isn't for your problem. That kind of thing simply does not *scale*. One person asking such a question that requires so much effort to answer might be OK. But 10? A hundred? It's ridiculous. That is exactly the kind of thing that leads to experts burning out and not answering anybody's questions.

Comment: @NicolBolas I didn't want to "fling a gigantic mound of code" at strangers, and that's why I asked this question. And we're trying to find a solution. I just don't get how you can miss the whole point of a question. Neither does "fling a gigantic mound of code" work nor this method of giving selective information work and that's the cause of this question. I just stated at the start that it's hard to do this kind of selective code providing for Vulkan and that's why I asked this question.

Comment: @ShambhavGautam: "*Neither does "fling a gigantic mound of code" work nor this method of giving selective information work and that's the cause of this question.*" I don't understand. There are only 3 possibilities: you give all of the code, you give some of the code, or you give none of the code. If you start from the position that none of these work, then... there's nothing more to do here. You've defined the problem as unsolveable.

Comment: @NicolBolas There are infinite real numbers between 1 and 2. Your answer does address that, but in vaguer terms "The issue then is primarily to figure out what "enough code" looks like." You yourself have accepted that the "enough code" can be different in every case, unlike this answer, which just says to give whatever the error-causing part seems to be.  The optimal answer to this question is some version of "some code but not all". I think we should show everything except the parts that we know can't cause the error. Btw, I've deleted the other 2 comments of mine.

Comment: This answer seems more like a StackOverflow answer. This has somehow mutated into a "Vulkan debugging tips and tricks", which belongs in StackOverflow. Techniques of debugging are indeed relevant to StackOverflow, people seem to forget that.

Comment: Nope.  A "Vulkan debugging tips and tricks" Q&A does NOT belong on StackOverflow ... either.

Comment: @StephenC The help page clearly states that a debugging question is not on topic unless it asks for certain techniques of debugging, which is just a posh tech-company way of saying "Debugging tips and tricks".

Comment: Well the flipside is that question that asks for tips and tricks is off-topic.  It is too broad.  There were a whole raft of tips and tricks questions from the old days that have been closed.

Answer (score 12):

It is understandable that some APIs or even programming languages are too verbose for problems in them to be reduced to a few lines of code. Indeed, this isn't even restricted to an API or language; particular problem domains often have lots of moving parts by nature, and reducing these isn't viable for whatever reason.

The issue then is primarily to figure out what "enough code" looks like. Ideally, you would just know from the problem what code people need to see, but odds are good that if you could do that easily, you wouldn't need to ask the question to begin with.

The general idea therefore is to provide what you think is the problem and what might be involved, along with a detailed explanation of what's going on and what other things you've done to localize the problem. If users think the problem lies elsewhere, they'll ask for more code. And when they do, be as complete as reasonable.

Comment: "Ideally, you would just know from the problem what code people need to see, but odds are good that if you could do that easily, you wouldn't need to ask the question to begin with." – There are techniques like the [*Saff Squeeze*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23865274/2988) that allow you to produce minimal testcases by mindlessly following two simple, stupid, almost-mechanical steps that do not require understanding of the problem domain.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Have you ever *seen* Vulkan code? The whole point of the thread is that the API is extremely *verbose*. Also, Vulkan isn't really a domain where "unit tests" work.

Comment: That's kind of the point of this thread. When you operate on Stack Overflow you kind of assume that the problem domain CAN be made small and contained, the entire site is geared towards it. Vulkan apparently is a very different beast where you do not have that option all that often. And that makes it really hard to ask questions about it on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Gimby: It's not an issue of the "problem domain" being too large. It's an issue of the *code size* being large. A problem with a smaller, less complex API like OpenGL could be boiled down much more effectively than the more verbose Vulkan, even if the problem itself is the same.

Comment: @Gimby I present to you [1500 LOC just to render a quad with a texture](https://github.com/Overv/VulkanTutorial/blob/master/code/26_depth_buffering.cpp). That's not a "wild out of scope problem domain". The same thing take an order of magnitude less code in OpenGL. This is why I said people who don't have experience in this domain literally cannot comprehend this problem in my answer.

Comment: I guess I used the wrong terminology, I'll take the blame for that.

Answer (score 0):

For the particular case of Vulkan (and [DirectX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX) 12?), I guess you might be able to get away with having somewhere (GitHub?) a few "standard code examples" (a few variations of a full renderer), change one of them with your code, as minimally as possible, and then post your question with the changed parts, the delta.

For "the pros" (say, AAA game developers) with complex (and proprietary?) scenarios that may not work, but for learners and casual developers it may.

(Caveat: I've done old OpenGL and DirectX 11 development, and  I've seen Vulkan specifications and code, but no real work, so apologies if I'm too far off.)