# How can I properly ask a question related to a less known SDK?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: ["this" pointer in constructor is not consistent with the address of the member object being initialised?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76985819/this-pointer-in-constructor-is-not-consistent-with-the-address-of-the-member-o)

I've encountered a problem with the VST SDK and asked this question.

High-reputation users first removed the "VST" tag from the question, which is essentially the whole background of it, and then criticized me for not providing a minimal reproducible code that could "compile and run", which I technically did provide.

To make an analogy: If I'm asking a Qt related question, then I need to include the whole Qt Framework and its build project file to provide a "minimal reproducible code that could compile and run", which is definitely not the case.

In the question I asked, I mentioned that it's based on the VST SDK, added a link to the SDK, and provided the two lines of code that can crash the program. I really do think I've provided enough context.

I'm not here to be a hater. I really want to discuss the definition of "minimal reproducible code that could compile and run", and how to ask questions related to a less known SDK since people who don't have the SDK would consider the code provided by author "does not compile and can't be debugged".

Comment: I also [raised the issue of your question, here on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426189/10871073).

Comment: @AdrianMole Many thanks for your care and the effort to raise a issue of the question. I'm relatively inexperienced in the community, and maybe not that good on asking a good question, but it did make me a bit sad. I'm not sure if it's proper to say but, your act provided me huge emotional support. Thank you!

Comment: Just a minor 'nit-pick': When we refer to "moderators" here on Meta, we normally mean those Diamond Moderators that were elected by the community and have enhanced powers. In the case of your question, the closure, deletion and editing (of the tags) were all done by 'normal' users, but ones with high reputation and some, limited moderation privileges.

Comment: As a comment on the original question you said: "*[A] "minimal" reproducible example won't be several lines of code since all the dependencies would be needed."* - 1) It sounds like what you were describing was not a **minimal** reproducible example.  You most likely can write the MRE so that it doesn't need all of the dependencies.  Yes, that is more work for you. But it is what we expect.

Comment: (continued) 2) It is not a requirement for an MRE to be "several lines of code".  It just needs to be as small as possible ... while satisfying the requirements to be complete, reproducible, and to fit within the SO limits on question length, etc.   In short, the criticism could be well-founded.

Comment: Obviously, you can assume that the MRE is reproducible in the context of the SDK.  Someone attempting to help you should be prepared to (say) download and install the SDK on their machine.  However, the flip-side is that if the SDK is rarely used, you may have to wait a long time for someone to turn up who is both willing and interested enough to go through that effort!

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413042/how-to-have-a-minimal-reproducible-example-with-vulkan

Comment: Close voting as duplicate - we don't need two specific-question Meta posts for the same main question.

Comment: @pppery: Both meta questions might be motivated by the same main question, but the meta questions are asking two entirely different things about how people should use the site. I don't think these qualify as duplicates.

Comment: @pppery you believe the answers to the two questions are *the same*?

Comment: @HirasawaYui *"No matter how you ask it, they'll just ignore you. Or even worse- they'll downvote you for no reason."* - This is obviously not true since a lot of questions gets upvoted and answered in a good way. 68% of my questions has a positive score and 86% has an answer.

Comment: @HirasawaYui To clarify. I do believe it's unnecessarily harsh here from time to time, and it happens often that questions get downvotes that can be discussed way to often. But your rant is so far from the truth that I believe it's counter productive. It gives the impression that's there is no reason to care, and it's bad if people act accordingly.