# What should we do with questions which reference a no-longer-available website for its example context?

Tags: discussion, minimal-reproducible-example

I came across [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316610/html-code-in-moving-a-part-of-header) while burninating [social](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/social), and I'm not sure what the best course of action is on this post. It's an old question, and it doesn't provide a code sample of their site, it only states their desired output and links to their now-defunct site as an example.

I don't come across webdev or WordPress questions often in the queues (they are not common for the filters I use normally), so I'm not sure whether linking to an external site would be an appropriate example in this case. I would assume myself that it is still lacking debugging details because we don't like links to external code samples for other topics. There are reasons we require MREs. I don't have a problem with the post linking to their own site; what I have an issue with is there is no MRE tied to the question, and the link which was provided is now dead.

However, due to the nature of web development... I could also see some believing this is acceptable for webdev questions (even if I would respectfully disagree since links can die at any time, as evidenced here).

Personally, I want to close this question as lacking details, since the little context given without the website link is too vague in my opinion. Even though it has accepted and upvoted answers I don't think it's going to be very useful to future visitors without the context the original website provided.

Note that there is one somewhat useful answer that does give *some* context around the original site's structure and the changes that could result in what OP wants. But just because an answer may be good, I feel questions should be judged on their own merits (and shortcomings) as well.

Comment: Even for web-related questions, it's not acceptable. Like you said, if a question is useless without the link, it should be closed. External links can sometimes be useful to provide *in addition* to the code that produces the behavior so question viewers can see a live demo easily, but the code should absolutely be present as well.

Comment: Close it for lacking detail.  See [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/208273)

Comment: That's my opinion as well @CertainPerformance, glad to see I'm not off base

Comment: Also, I'm not sure that that answer has any value without the accompanying website.

Comment: Pretty much the same guidance as [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428) I would say.

Comment: @RyanM Thanks for that link. That actually answers this question, I did not find it when I searched before asking. I've VTC'd this as a dupe.

Comment: @RyanM The 1-vote answer does show the before/after of the CSS which was modified, which I do think provides some context and makes the answer more useful. However, you are correct that the website would be necessary for full context which the answer still lacks (though it is not on the answerer to provide context which the asker has omitted).

Comment: Also close but not an exact overlap: [What should a 'minimal, reproducible example' include for problems with automating web browsers using Selenium?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405791)